# Remediation for Unsafe Encryption Mode Usage

Tags: android, android-security

I am trying to update the application. However, Google rejected it because we could not use AES/ECB/NoPadding. The reason we use AES/ECB/NoPadding is to connect a Bluetooth device, but if you change the encryption part, the device will not connect. What should I do?